# With AMD modules, when (or why) is it OK to use require() within define()?

Tags: requirejs, js-amd, curljs

My understanding of AMD modules (using for example RequireJs or curl.js) is:

`require()` is used to asynchronously load different modules and when loaded then the callback fn is executed.

And to define a module, you would have separate scripts that use `define()`

But I've seen some modules use `require()` inside their function definition, e.g.

```
define([a, b, c], function(i, ii, iii){ 
    require([d, e, f], function(d, e, f) {
        // do some stuff with these require()'d dependancies
    })
    /* rest of the code for this module */ 
})
```

But I find this confusing because I would have thought that if a module has dependancies then they should be passed through via the main `define([dependancies], fnDefinition)` function and not within it via `require()` as per the above example is doing.

Is there a reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a few reasons you may want to use `require()` in a module.

But first, be sure you request a reference to the correct `require` variable.  In your example, the reference to `require` is a *global*.  You want a reference to a `require` that is scoped to the context of your module (sometimes called a "local require").  This is easy:

```
define(["a", "b", "c", "require"], function(i, ii, iii, require){ 
    require(["d", "e", "f"], function(moduleD, moduleE, moduleF) {
        // do some stuff with these require()'d dependencies
    })
    /* rest of the code for this module */ 
});
```

The main reason this is important is to ensure that relative module ids (e.g. "./peerModule" or "../unclePath/cousinModule") are resolved correctly.  (This is one of the reasons, curl.js doesn't have a global `require` by default.)

---

Reasons to use a local `require`:

1. you don't know which modules are needed at build time (or at load time) due to run-time conditions
2. you explicitly want to defer loading of some modules until they're needed
3. you want to load a variation of a module based on results of feature detection (although something like dojo's "has!" plugin might be a better solution ( sorry, link eluding me))

Lastly, AMD defines a second usage of `require` for compatibility with modules authored in the CommonJS Modules/1.1 which are then wrapped in a `define`.  These look like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module){ 
    var a = require("pkgZ/moduleA"), // dependency
        b = require("pkgZ/moduleB"); // dependency
    /* rest of the code for this module */ 
});
```

Server-side javascript devs may find this format appealing. :)

Some AMD loaders (such as RequireJS 0.2+, dojo 1.7+, bdLoad, and curl.js 0.6+) will detect this hybrid AMD/CJSM1.1 format and find dependencies by scanning the module for `require` calls.

Comment: best link I can find for has.js: http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-contributors/2011-January/023462.html It doesn't explain the plugin, just mentions it.

Comment: if anybody has enough points to create a curljs tag, i'd appreciate it! :)

Comment: So if I have module that needs certain functionality which isn't available in all browsers, I can define the module as normal and then inside I can can do a conditional check and then require() the relevant modules that polyfill the missing functionality, is that right? And I'm assuming that at 'build time' I could still minify that module using my build script so it's not like i'm asynchronously loading an un-minified module script.

Comment: Correct, that's the purpose of the has! plugin.  The intent is to build up a map of UA strings* to feature profiles.  Your server can either choose a custom-tuned file from a list of pre-compiled, concatenated files for the current browser's UA string -- or it can build one just-in-time (and hopefully cache it for later use). *It should be noted that not everybody is "on board" with reintroducing UA sniffing!

Comment: Does this hold true for a first entry point "require" specified after the require.config() block? I have enforceDefine set to true, which puts the config block inside a define(), then the entry point is called using the global "require" just after config.