# Selectively loading AMD modules using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm having a use case where I've to load `AMD` modules depending on some condition in order to define another module using `requirejs`.

```
define(['module1'],
    function(module1)
    {
      /*some code*/

      if (condition1) {
        require(['module2'],
            function()
            {
                /*some code*/
            }
        )        
      }
      else {
         require(['module3'],
            function()
            {
               /*some code*/
            }
        )     
    }
    return someObject;
    });
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835116/with-amd-modules-when-or-why-is-it-ok-to-use-require-within-define) question and got confused with global and local `require`.
Is the above approach correct ?

Comment: does it work or not ?

Comment: Yes, it works though I use commonJS style in my code.
    `define(['require','module1'],function(require,module1))
    {
      var module2 = require('module2');
  
      return something;
    }`

Comment: really it works? To me it does not work because module2 wasnt loaded before. An I get the error: module2 has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]). That means it needs to be assync. How can I do to do sync? Get module2 with require("module2") the first time I call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the 'local' `require`. The local require will make sure modules are resolved relative to the 'parent' module,

```
define(["require", "module1"], function(require, module1) {
    require(['./relative/to/parent/not/necessarily/relative/to/baseUrl'], ...);
```

and that URLs are also resolved relative to the 'parent' module.

```
define(["require", "module1"], function(require, module1) {
    require.toUrl('./relative/to/parent/not/necessarily/relative/to/baseUrl')
```

Comment: I believe that can be shortened to `define(function(require) { //... })`

Comment: Yeah I think the OP needs to import `module1` as well, so maybe that format cannot be used in this case. I'll update my answer to be more explicit.